# How do I return a value even if there's a mismatch in case?

Tags: c#

How do I return a value even if there's a mismatch in case?

For example, I have an array with the string "alex". A user searches through the array and types "AlEx" by accident. How do I return the original value "alex"?

I am currently using C#.

```
public bool DoesCarExist(string ID)
{
    if (_indentifiers.Contains(ID))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;
}

[Test]
public void TestCaseSensitive()
{
    bool expected = true;
    Car Cars = new Car(new string[] { "Nissan" });

    // this should return true even if NiSSan is entered
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, Cars.DoesCarExist("NiSSan"));
}
```

Comment: Add your code, please

Comment: I have added sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple ways of comparing strings while ignoring case differences.

**Example 1:**

```
string str1 = "MyStrinGVAlue";
string str2 = "MystringvaLUE";

str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) // returns true
```

**Example 2:**

```
string str1 = "MyStrinGVAlue";
string str2 = "MystringvaLUE";

str1.ToLowerCase() == str2.ToLowerCase() // returns true
```

***Note:*** The first way is more efficient as it does not need to create new instance of the string.

Comment: sorry i am still confused as i am using this for unit testing, i have included a sample of my code, i tried implementing your method but it didn't work.

Comment: Now that I see you code example.. You are trying to use Contains. One easy way would be to replace that condition to `if (_indentifiers.IndexOf(ID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)`